# Find and update individual element in array Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I's like to update or insert a (new) element into an array in Mongo (Using Mongoose).

The schema looks like this:

```
let fieldsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  recordCreatedAt: Date,
  recordUpdatedAt: Date,
  userId: {
    type: String,
    lowercase: true,
    validate: (value) => {
      return validator.isEmail(value);
    },
  },
  customerId: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
    unique: false,
  },
  fields: {
    type: Array,
    required: false,
    unique: false,
  },
});
```

'fields' will either be an empty array or contain data of the form:

```
[{fieldId:something},{fieldVal:somethingElse}...{fieldId:testing},{fieldVal:somethingTest}]
```

I'd like to run an update function that:

1. Finds a document with a matching `userId`
2. Either inserts a new element to array `{fieldId:something},{fieldVal:somethingElse}` if `fieldId` doesn't already exist
3. Or updates an existing array element based on `fieldId` if it already exists as a key somewhere in the array.

So if this document exists:

```
{
    userId: 1,
    customerId: 1,
    fields: [{fieldId:something},{fieldVal:somethingElse}]
}
```

And an update operation is passed which includes `{fieldId:something}`, then `{fieldVal:somethingElse}` is updated to give:

```
{
    userId: 1,
    customerId: 1,
    fields: [{fieldId:something},{fieldVal:NEWDATA}]
}
```

However, if `fields` does not have an element which matches on `fieldId`, then the element `{fieldId:something},{fieldVal:NEWDATA}` is inserted into the array to achive the same result.

I've so far tried all manner of $push and $set type operations, with varying degrees of success. I can iteratively add new elements to the array with $push, but it doesn't respect the fact that `fieldId:something` already exists, and always creates a new element in the array.

I'm currently using $set as below, but this returns as error: `The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.` presumably because it needs creating first - But how to create if not exists in the same update operation?

```
 const findClientField = await FieldsModel.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        clientId: req.body.userId,
      },
      {
        $set: { 'fields.$.fieldId': `yourValue` },
      },
      {
        new: true,
        upsert: true,
      }
    );
    console.log(findClientField);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  } finally {
    res.status(200).send(`Field saved.`);
  }
```